# How to switch off autocorrection for soft keyboard in native (NDK) app?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using the next code to show soft keyboard in my NDK (based on `NativeActivity`) app:

```
    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.showSoftInput(getWindow().getDecorView(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

I need to switch off autocorrection. I learned that on order to do it, I need to override `View.onCreateInputConnection` method:

```
InputConnection onCreateInputConnection (EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    InputConnection ic = new EditableInputConnection(this);
    outAttrs.inputType = TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
    return ic;
}
```

The problem is that the view I am using is `getWindow().getDecorView()`, so I cannot inherit from it and override anything.

What would you suggest? Would it be somehow possible to "listen" or "intercept" `onCreateInputConnection` method of existing view (`getWindow().getDecorView()`)?

Comment: I think theres the same flag in the TextView component, can't you use it?

Comment: There is no `TextView` in `NativeActivity`.

Comment: Of course native activities have text views.  They have access to any class in the SDK via JNI if nothing else.

Comment: You are listening the keyboard then to a Canvas? Anyway.. the other way is to make JNI calls to the Java methods you want.

Comment: Actually, you don't have any view? you can override it in any

Comment: You can file bugs for missing NDK APIs: https://b.android.com

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally do that.  Normally you'd set the type of the edit text when you create it to include that flag.  (And of course remember that the individual keyboard may or may not honor that flag, its up to them).

Comment: I do not have `EditText` in `NativeActivity`.

Comment: What actual view do you have connected to the keyboard?  Because if you aren't using an EditText, you're probably doing everything wrong.  Actually interacting with a keyboard in Android is a very non-trivial task unless you use TextView or a subclass.

Comment: I have an OpenGL game application written mostly in C++. There are no any Android widgets: no `View`s, no `TextView`s, no `EditText`s. But I need to allow user to input some information.

Comment: @Nick You have to have a view.  Only  views can appear on screen.  YOu may be doing it with a single SurfaceView showing an OpenGL buffer, but you absolutely have a view.

Comment: Yes. I have some view. And this is what created for me automatically - and I can access it as `getWindow().getDecorView()` from within NativeActivity. But the type of this view is not `EditText`

Comment: @Nick Then you need to subclass the view you're setting as the context view (which is being returned by getDecorView) and override onCreateInputConnection.  And implement the entire inputConnection, which is a VERY non-trivial task to get right.  You're better off jumping through whatever hoops it takes to use an EditText than doing it yourself.

Comment: But that's not me who sets the context view. It is done in NativeActivity.java which is a part of SDK.